# Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudAppendBlob' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.3.0.0

Tags: azure, azure-storage, custom-activity

I am running a custom activity in Azure data factory, when i am trying to work on CloudAppendBlob the following exception occurs. It looks like a version issue but not able to figure a way to fix. I have compiled the code using Windows Azure Storage 7.0.0.  Please help!

Unknown error in module:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could
>   not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudAppendBlob'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. at
>   MyDotNetActivity.SampleActivity.Execute(IEnumerable`1 linkedServices,
>   IEnumerable`1 datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger) at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.Execute(Object
>   job, String configuration, Action`1 logAction) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.DataPipeline.Compute.HDInsightJobExecution.ReflectingActivityWrapper.Execute()
>   in
>   f:_Bld\12752\4106\Sources\Product\Common\Compute\src\HDIComputeDelegatorJob\ReflectingActivityWrapper.cs:line
>   44 at
>   Microsoft.DataPipeline.Compute.HDInsightJobExecution.JobWrapper.RunJob()
>   in
>   f:_Bld\12752\4106\Sources\Product\Common\Compute\src\HDIComputeDelegatorJob\JobWrapper.cs:line
>   94 at
>   Microsoft.DataPipeline.Compute.HDInsightJobExecution.Launcher.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   f:_Bld\12752\4106\Sources\Product\Common\Compute\src\HDIComputeDelegatorJob\Launcher.cs:line
>   78.

Comment: Are you sure you're using version 7.0.0.0 of the library? From the error it seems you're using 4.3.0.0.

Comment: Seems like you need to update your project's assembly binding.

Comment: Where do you run your app? May be, you already have the 4.3.0.0 version in GAC, and your app load it from there.

Comment: I run the app in Azure, here is the link I follow https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/   and example for Append blob is here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have run into the same problem myself. Turns out Azure Data Factory is restricted to version 4.3 of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage. In order to load a different version you should take a look at Microsoft's [CrossAppDomainDotNetActivitySample](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/CrossAppDomainDotNetActivitySample).

From the readme:

> This sample allows you to author a custom .NET activity for ADF that is not constrained to assembly versions used by the ADF launcher (e.g., WindowsAzure.Storage v4.3.0, Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.x, etc.).
>
> The code includes an abstract base class (CrossAppDomainDotNetActivity) that implements app-domain isolation and a sample derived class (MyDotNetActivity) that demonstrates using WindowsAzure.Storage v6.2.0.
>
> Note: The public types exposed by the ADF SDK are not serializable across app domain boundaries. As such, the derived class must provide pre-execution logic (PreExecute) to process the ADF objects into a serializable object that is then passed to the core logic (ExecuteCore).

Comment: This is a known limitation of the DotNetActivity - and the recommended workaround is the one Mitchell mentions here. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c09ca5c-4391-4d5c-bd10-ebc59f4c444c/azure-blob-storage-exception-in-custom-activity?forum=AzureDataFactory

Answer (score 0):

In your app.config, add the following [assembly binding redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

If you encountered other similar issues afterwards, add assembly binding redirects for those assemblies as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but exception persists even after adding the assembly binding redirect.    And my app.config is having the code

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup></configuration>'